# regex expression to replace everything in a string between 2 like characters?

Tags: regex-group, regexp-replace

This seems simple but I am not very familiar with regex so I'm having hard time finding a solution.

I have a date/time in string format that looks like this:

> "11/18/2022 12:00 AM"

I want to create another property that is just a day ahead (so "11/19/2022 12:00 AM"), so I need a regex expression that just points to the "18" in that string.

Any help or guidance is appreciated! Thanks.

I've tried this:

> ^(.)(.*)(./[^/]*)$

which just replaces the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

You could match the pattern with capture groups and use those groups in the replacement.

The value for `18` is in capture group 2, and the leading and trailing part in group 1 and group 3 in case you want to do a replacement.

```
^(\d{1,2}/)(\d{1,2})(/\d{4}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s[AP]M)$
```

See a [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/MevWzY/1)

Note that when you want to increment the date with a day, it would be better to match the string and then use a programming language with a date function/api.